# How to calculate the rotated angle from OpenCV rvecs

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, aruco

I am using aruco markers to get the location of a robot. After getting the pose from the estimatePoseSingleMarkers i obtain the rvecs and tvecs for a given marker. From this how could i obtain the rotated angle of the marker about each axis.

i used the code below to detect and draw the aruco markers along with its axis

```
while(true)
{
    vector< vector<Point2f>> corners; //All the Marker corners 
    vector<int> ids;

    cap >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    aruco::detectMarkers(gray, dictionary, corners, ids);
    aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(frame,corners,ids);
    aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, arucoMarkerLength, cameraMatrix, distanceCoefficients, rvecs, tvecs);

    for(int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++)
    {
        aruco::drawAxis(frame, cameraMatrix, distanceCoefficients, rvecs[i], tvecs[i], 0.1f);
    }

    imshow("Markers", frame);
    int key = waitKey(10);
    if((char)key == 'q')
        break;
}
```

Comment: [Rodrigues](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac)

Comment: I checked it but it gives some values what i want is the angle rotated in degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation of the marker with respect to the camera was obtained by first taking the rotation matrix from the rotation vector(rvec) and then by taking the euler angle. 
[Converting Rotation matrix to Eurler angles are given here](https://www.learnopencv.com/rotation-matrix-to-euler-angles/)